# Should I use Start or Update to call the given method in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

1.I have a class in which I have a method called `ProjectileMotion()` with return type IEnumerator and this method is being called from Start().
2. The above script is attached to a prefab that is instantiated from another class.

Problem:

In IENumerator ProjectileMotion() method, I need to have updated position of an object which is moving continuously,so I declared

```
//assigned the o=gameobject to it and it is moving continuously
Public Transform Target;
```

In ProjectileMotion(), if I do Target.transform,position, it gives the starting position only and not where it was at the time of instantiation of the prefab to which this script is attached, However, I am able to get the updated position of `Target`  in Update method(checked using Debug.Log).

But I can not call the ProjectileMotion() in Update method of course, what should I do to get updated position of Target every time the prefab is instantiated and so the script is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put ...

If you want the code to execute when the component is "started" then call it on start.

OR

If you want the code to execute each frame after the component has started then call it on update.

Judging by the name of this method I would think this is something that updates the position of a projectile after a gun has instantiated it.
The position being updated is likely a per frame operation so.

I would put this in the update method.

EDIT:

UNLESS ...

Does this function do a multiframe animation?

Unity has the concept of coroutines that allow to do certain actions of several frames. in this case you might be better off doing something like this in your start method ...

```
StartCoroutine(ProjectileMotion)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing in start() method, but the problem is in Strat() method, I am not getting the updated position of Target , which as I mentioned above I have declared in the script which guides motion of projectile, I need to know the position of Target at the point the script was instantiated in Player class.

Comment: There is no multiframe animation

Comment: so this thing you just instantiated is a projectile and it needs to know what it was shot or just the direction in which it was shot? I would think just the direction until a collision test is done that says "you hit this thing" which presumably is part of that co routine.

Comment: For getting the target presumably the gun / thing that did the targeting would know that and could pass it in when creating the new projectile object? (at least that's how I would go about it)